# UI object for attachment bar on new post page in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

Sorry for quite a dumb question, I'm new to iOS development.

I'm making an application which would able user to post, say something similar to Facebook or Twitter. Currently I'm making the 'New Post' page. I'm trying to find what is the UI object for an attachment bar, which will contain icon to add picture / character count, etc. Or if no such simple UI object exists, how can we make it?

The bar I meant is the light grey bar above the keyboard shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what i mean is Toolbar